# Is there a strchr with boundary?

Tags: c++, c, string

There is a `char *strchr( const char *str, int ch )` function defined in `<string.h>`.

It has no boundary, after which it stops the search.

Is there a similar function somewhere, which you can pass a boundary to?

**Edit:**

I have a `char* pos` and a length of a ***substring*** and I want to find a specific ASCII character in it, but I don't want it to search up to the very null-terminator, because I don't care for the second part of the character sequence.

Comment: There obviously is such a boundary - it's a NUL (zero) character terminating the `str` string. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr

Comment: I don't think there anything like `strnchr` in the standard library.  You can write it yourself in about three lines.

Comment: What's your boundary? A number of characters, or a specific sentinel character in addition to the usual 0 byte?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

`void* memchr( const void* ptr, int ch, size_t count )`

Comment: The can search past the end of the _string_, unlike `strchr()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica. You can compare both results, or otherwise ensure you aren't passing, e.g. with strlen

Comment: `memchr(str, chr, min(strlen(str), target))`

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Or you just do `strchr` and compare the pointer to the found character to the desired bound - only needs one pass over the string, instead of your two passes.  But these all have the problem that the worst-case time taken will be on the order of the length of the string, even if that is much longer than the bound you specified.

Comment: @NateEldredge. Then you need `strnlen`, which does `min(strlen(s), n)` but without checking the whole string. You can implement it recursively by calling `memchr(s, 0, n)`

Comment: @NateEldredge. Calling it twice fixes the problem. Posted an answer

Comment: Hello everyone writing here stuff like "this can search past the end of the string". I can assure you it won't do this in my case because I am the one who posted the question and I know what I was looking for. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @a_girl Thanks for clarifying, but we like to make these answers useful for the next person who comes along, too.  In general, and by analogy with the way existing functions like `strncpy` and `strncat` work, I would say that a general-purpose `strnchr` function must absolutely be written to allow both for the possibility that the actual string is shorter than `n`, as well as the possibility that the "string" pointed to is not properly terminated at all.

Answer (score 1):

As the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851433/2988730) points out, you can use `memchr`, but you'll need to call it twice if you want to avoid going out of bounds:

```
char *strnchr(const char *s, int c, size_t n)
{
    char *nul = memchr(s, 0, n);
    if(!c) return nul;
    if(nul) n = nul - s;
    return memchr(s, c, n); 
}
```

With the right hardware optimization, this may be more efficient than just checking the first `n` characters:

```
char *strnchr(const char *s, int c, size_t n)
{
     for(char *p = s; (p - s) < n; p++) {
         if(*p == c) return p;
         if(!*p) break;
     }
     return NULL;
}
```

Comment: It is easy to code this and I would certainly do this in my own pet project, but the problem is - I am not allowed to add such functions to the project at my work. I have to either use the standard c/c++ library or the functions/methods which already exist in the code.

Comment: @a_girl. That sounds like a terrible project. Where did those functions come from anyway?

Comment: you are correct that it is terrible. The functions were written by "the most experienced" developer there over the course of the last 20 years. The project/compiler itself still uses c++98 mostly and is theoretically capable of c++03. It is all due to the dependency on QNX operating system. And not even the latest version of it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course just call `strchr` and compare the result against the desired bound.

```
char *strnchr(const char *s, int c, size_t n)
{
    char *p = strchr(s, c);
    if (p && (p-s) < n)
        return p;
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

This does mean that if the string is much longer than `n` characters, and the desired character `c` is not found in the first `n`, then the call to `strchr` may go on to search the whole rest of the string, wasting time.  Mad Physicist's answer avoids this, but at the cost of either making two passes over the string, or writing your own loop which may not take advantage of highly optimized library string functions.

Comment: A usual reason for a bound `n` to to cope with cases where `s` does not properly point to a _string_ (_null character_ missing) and avoid the UB of `strchr(s, c)`.

Comment: It is easy to code this and I would certainly do this in my own pet project, but the problem is - I am not allowed to add such functions to the project at my work. I have to either use the standard c/c++ library or the functions/methods which already exist in the code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a `strchr` with boundary?

There is not a standard library solution that mimics `strchr()` with a size limit.

Easy enough to code one though.

**Loop termination**

To form a `strnchr(const char* ptr, int ch, size_t size)` obliges a loop to stop on one of 3 cases:

- Match found (`*ptr == ch`)
- *Null character* found (`*ptr == '\0'`)
- Iteration meets `size`.

**Common mistakes**:

- Compare using `ch` and not the correct `(char) ch`.
- Special consideration when `ch == 0`.  `strchr(s, 0)` returns a pointer to the null character.
- Special consideration when `size == 0`.  A return of `NULL` is expected, not UB.
- Using `int size` and not `size_t`.
- Using `char *ptr` and not `const char *ptr`.

**Direct implementation**:

```
char *strnchr(const char* ptr, int ch, size_t size) {
  while (size > 0) {
    size--;
    if (*ptr == (char) ch) {
      return ptr;
    } 
    if (*ptr == '\0') {
      break;
    } 
    ptr++;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

**Efficiency**

Let `len = length of string` (unbounded if not exist), `m = match offset` (unbounded if not exist),

This solution is `O(min(len, m, size))`.  Other posted solutions are are `O(min(m, max(len, size))`, `O(min(len, m, size))`, `O(min(len, m) with UB)`, `O(min(m, size) with UB)`.

Get correct functionality first, then optimize.

I'll leave optimization ideas for others.

---

**Reference: `strchr()`**

> The `strchr` function locates the first occurrence of `c` (converted to a `char`) in the string pointed to by `s`. The terminating null character is considered to be part of the string.

> The `strchr` function returns a pointer to the located character, or a null pointer if the character does not occur in the string.

Comment: A typical use case for `while (size --> 0)` :)

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, the _arrow_ operator.  I think its fun, but it attracks flack.

Comment: It is easy to code this and I would certainly do this in my own pet project, but the problem is - I am not allowed to add such functions to the project at my work. I have to either use the standard c/c++ library or the functions/methods which already exist in the code.